# How to convert a JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JToken with the value {1234}

How can I convert this to an Integer value as var totalDatas = 1234;

```
var tData = jObject["$totalDatas"];
int totalDatas = 0;
if (tData != null)
   totalDatas = Convert.ToInt32(tData.ToString());
```

Comment: Just cast it... it's a number.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use the [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) method.

```
JToken token = ...;
int value = token.ToObject<int>();
```

Answer (score 14):

You should use:

```
int totalDatas = tData.Value<Int32>();
```

Comment: No such syntax - .Value<int>(object key) takes one argument

Answer (score 6):

You can simply cast the `JToken` to `int` :

```
string json = @"{totalDatas : ""1234""}";
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken token = obj["totalDatas"];
int result = (int)token;

//print 2468
Console.WriteLine(result*2);
```

**[[.NET fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4uQeyF)]**

Answer (score 2):

try this:
int value = (int)token.Value;

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, even if it is right, try to explain a little bit. If there are some other answers, show the Pros and Cons of your P.O.V.