# Checking value of JSON property fails to compare to string

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm building user registration and store user data in JSON files. For some reason I can't compare value of a property to string. Sample code:

```
public bool IsRegistered()
{
    JObject data = JObject.Parse("{\"Registered\":\"yes\"}");
    var registered = data["Registered"];
    if (registered != "yes")
    {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get error on  `if (registered != "yes")`

> operator of type != cannot be used in operand of type JToken and string

Comment: `data["Registred"]` this looks to be misspelled. Is it supposed to be `data["Registered"]`? Also, what's the error? Post all you can to help us figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by you get an error? Will the code compile and run? Is it just not doing what you expect?

Comment: error is operator of type != cannot be used in operand of type JToken and string

Comment: Not it dont compile

Comment: data["Register"] is probably type of object. It cannot cast it to string. Try the follow var nwm = (string)data["Registred"];

Comment: yes it is working now with (string)data["Registred"]; thank you !

Comment: This also may help for other things you do with JToken https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870698/how-to-convert-a-jtoken

Comment: @NoobGuy123 If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Because the `registered` is of type [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) and so you can not compare it with a `string`. You can cast to `string` like this:

```
var registered = (string)data["Registred"];
if (registered != "yes")
```